# Missing CDRom on Ubuntu Server install inside a Virtual Box VM on Windows 10 Pro host

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have just downloaded Ubuntu Server from Ubuntu website.

I have installed Ubuntu Server inside a Virtual Box VM on a Windows 10 Pro Host (This host does NOT have a physical CDRom drive)

I have gone to install the Virtual Box Guest Additions but there is no virtual CDRom.

I tried various different tutorials with sudo around...

```
mkdir /media/cdrom
mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
cd /media/cdrom
sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

however the CDRom was either not created or was created inside the media folder but I could not access it as it kept saying I did not have permission.

Can someone tell me how to create a virtual CDRom so I can install the Virtual Box Guest Additions.

I have wiped the previous tries of VM, so now I just have a vanilla install of Server ready to start again.
Thanks

Comment: You mention Ubuntu Server, but you weren't clear as to which Ubuntu Server product (Ubuntu Server itself, or the *flavor* of Ubuntu Core Server), nor what release of that product..  Please be specific.  The CDROM may refer to the installation media; but your description reads more as a HOST problem (ie. windows 10 configuration issue of virtualbox with your *unstated* Ubuntu product in the VM)

Comment: I download Ubuntu Server 23.04 from https://ubuntu.com/download/server
Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 LTS installs fine in Virtual Box and I can see the virtual cdrom drive ok and install VB guest additions.